# ros answer sub board

Tags: ros, meta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is ros answer able to create sub board that could ask robotics question not just related with ROS utility? Such as probability robotics,inverse kinematics,opencv,RS232,laser range finder...etc.
Of course all these ideas could programmed by ROS.
If any place can ask such questions, that would be very great to push robotics~
Because I found even in [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=users) doesn't have any robotics board.
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10156/ros-answer-sub-board/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this proposal for a StackExchange site that looks a bit like what you are looking for: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29987/robotics-research . Note that that's just a proposal for a StackExchange site and isn't up and running yet.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-06**:
I'm pretty sure those numbers are what it still needs. When I followed it, the number of followers needed was higher, so I'm guessing that those are counters for what is left.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-06-06**:
I think that meets all the requirements, am I right?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-06**:
When enough people say they are interested in it by following it and it has enough on and off topic questions. There is an info thing in the top right that says "This proposal is still in Definition" and lists the requirements for moving to the next stage.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-06-05**:
Great~~So, when that board could be available?